# Why do I run out of Memory while capturing images?

Tags: wpf, memory

After about 10s I get an exception that there is insufficient memory.

[image]

The error occurs in this code where the images are captured and display on UI:

```
private void onFrameEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    uEye.Camera Camera = sender as uEye.Camera;

    Int32 s32MemID;
    Camera.Memory.GetActive(out s32MemID);


    // Read Camera bitmap
    Bitmap bitmap;
    Camera.Memory.ToBitmap(s32MemID, out bitmap);


    Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        // Convert bitmap to WPF-Image
        var bmp = new Bitmap(bitmap);
        var hBitmap = bmp.GetHbitmap();

        System.Windows.Media.ImageSource wpfBitmap = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
            hBitmap, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty,
            BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

        image1.Source = wpfBitmap;
        image1.Stretch = System.Windows.Media.Stretch.UniformToFill;

        DeleteObject(hBitmap);
    }));
}
```

How can I avoid such huge memory access?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this language and forgive me for being ignorant, but when you read in the image and store it as a bitmap...once you're done with it, do you free that memory?  It doesn't look like you are.  I see `hBitmap` is being cleared, but not `bitmap`

Comment: You are right and I also used "bitmap.dispose()" but it has the same effect. What I found out is, you can use the "GC.Collect()" which solves the problem.
But I am not really 100% convinced if this is the right way or not!

Comment: Only a comment but I recall seeing something that another error with images is incorrectly reported as an OOM.

Comment: Lots of strange things here: You create a bitmap on one thread, then run a delegate on the UI thread that just _copies_ the original bitmap and works with it, but you never dispose of either bitmap. And the bitmap is passed by capture instead of passing it as an object to [Dispatcher.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc647509(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @ Panagiotis: Could you please tell me how I need to change my code to pass the bitmap as an object to Dispatcher.Invoke?

Answer (score 0):

I an into memory issues with WPF and images a few years back. It seems like it's a bug in WPF.

The following code seems to have deal with it. The difference seems to be that you aren't calling source.Freeze(), bitmap.Dispose() and GC.Collect(). I assume DeleteObject is the same as mine.

```
public static class BitmapEx
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a Bitmap object to WPF 'ImageSource' object and 
    /// garbage collects to Bitmap object.
    /// </summary>
    public static ImageSource ToImageSource(this Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        IntPtr hBitmap = bitmap.GetHbitmap();
        try
        {
            ImageSource source = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                    hBitmap, 
                    IntPtr.Zero,
                    Int32Rect.Empty,
                    BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions()
            );

            source.Freeze();
            return source;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (!Win32Image.DeleteObject(hBitmap))
                Debug.WriteLine("BitmapEx.ToImageSource() - Unable to Delete hBitmap");   

            bitmap.Dispose();
            bitmap = null;
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
}

[SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode)]
public static class Win32Image
{
    public static bool DeleteObject(IntPtr handle)
    {
        return NativeMethods.DeleteObject(handle);
    }

    private static class NativeMethods
    {
        [DllImport("gdi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);
    }
}
```

I still ran into problems when loading a large number of images (50+) into a window, in hindsight this was probably caused by the GC.Collect() call (I just didn't load the images on that page). If you run into that problem, you could probably try and limit the number of times you call GC.Collect().

[EDIT]

Calling GC.Collect() is considered a bad idea (see comments).

Try using the code without GC.Collect(). If it works for you then I'll remove the GC.Collect() line from this answer.

Comment: Forgetting to call `Freeze` and `Dispose` is a bug in the code, not WPF. Once you do this, calling `GC.Collect` won't prevent an OutOfMemoryException because the garbage collector simply clears the memory that would be collected anyway if there was memory pressure. This simply wastes CPU cycles and freezes the thread while garbage collection is taking place. You could argue that it would also release GDI objects that weren't disposed properly but that's a bug in the code too

Comment: Well it definitely fixed the memory issues I was having. Though at the time I was running into high memory usage (100MB) rather than a full on OutOfMemoryException.

Comment: That's not an issue if no-one else needs this memory, but it will cost when the GC finally runs. Again, this is not a bug in WPF. If you create a lot of objects, you'll get a lot of objects to cleanup. The solution is to reuse objects (particularly buffers) as much as possible, eg by reusing a byte array or use [BufferManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.buffermanager.aspx) to do it for you.

Comment: I edited my answer with a line about trying it without GC.Collect(). If it works without GC.Collect() I'll remove it. If another working answer comes along, I'll put a note stating using GC.Collect() bad idea and that anyone looking for a solution should give the other answer a shot first.

Comment: even I use the bitmap.Dispose() in my code, I still get the memory exception. In case I use the GC_Collect() it works perfectly.

Comment: Are you calling source.Freeze() as well? Even if it doesn't seem to make a difference, doing that is a good idea.

Comment: I tried it with source.Freeze() but it had no positive effect. Any idea?

Comment: @Panagiotis: How can I pass the bitmap as an object to Dispatcher.Invoke on my code (see above)?